# Position <div> relative to lower-right corner of div envelope

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm working with some js plotting libraries ([`flot`](http://www.flotcharts.org/), to be specific), and trying to deal with adding mouse-over tooltips to show the value of the plotted data that the mouse points to.

Right now, I have an event that calls a function that shows the tooltip. The event provides the mouse pointer position as `x, y` coordinates.

Since most mouse pointers point up and to the left, I want to position the tooltip `<div>` up and to the left of the `x, y`. However, the contents of the div are dynamic, and as far as I can tell, there is no way to specify that a div is positioned from the lower-right extent of the div's overall size.

Right now, all my spacing is hard-coded, and it doesn't handle long contents well:

Good:
[image]

Bad:
[image]
<sub>The circle is the data-point currently being mouse-over-ed. It is what I have coordinates for</sub>

Since I'm using `flot`, I have jQuery. The snippet that generates the div is:

```
        function showTooltip(x, y, contents, z) {
            $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                top: y - 30,
                left: x - 80,
                'font-weight':'bold',
                border: '1px solid rgb(255, 221, 221)',
                padding: '2px',
                'background-color': z,
                opacity: '0.8'
            }).appendTo("body").show();
        };
```

I haven't had much luck searching for answers, since googling "div position relative" gives lots results for positioning div's relative to each other, and nothing about positioning them relative to their extents.

If I were drawing this using a more traditional UI toolkit, I'd call the `getExtents()` function of the div, and use the returned dimensions to apply an offset to the div's position, but I don't know where to even look for that kind of approach here.

It's also been years since I've dealt with web programming of any sort, so I may be missing something obvious.

---

More edit: Better pictures:

How the div is being positioned.
[image]

How I want to be able to position it.
[image]

(dimensions are nonsense, ignore them)

---

EDIT: JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/2694/

String length changes depending on whether the data-point is > 0. Try mousing over the upper and lower sections of the graph to see the issue.

Comment: Can you please put together a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @monners - I'm hacking on a existing app. I don't know if I'm competent to create something from scratch.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but have you tried changing `top: x - 80` to `top: x + 80` ? (to shift it to the right)

Comment: @monners - Gah, typo, I mean upper left. basically, I want the pointer to point to the *lower right* corner of the pop-up tooltip, which means it's positioned to the upper-*left*. Derp.

Comment: `top` and `left` are your positioning values.  Play around with those.

Comment: I tried changed `top` and `left`.  They set where the absolute coordinates are evaluated from. Right now, coordiate `0,0` is in the upper left corner of the viewport. Changing them sets it in the lower right respectively. This is not helpful, since the coordinates I get from the event handler are assuming `0.0` is in the upper left corner. All it does is mean the tooltip moves opposite from mouse movement, which is not desireable at all.

Comment: JSFiddle demo in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using static values (`y-30` and `x-80`), so larger `contents`will overlap (right). try some dynamic positioning

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/2716/)

```
function showTooltip(x, y, contents, z) {
    var offset = 10; // use higher values for a little spacing between `x,y` and tooltip
    // first create tag in DOM
    var elem = $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').appendTo("body").show();

    elem.css({ //style it
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'inline-block',
        'font-weight':'bold',
        border: '1px solid rgb(255, 221, 221)',
        padding: '2px',
        'background-color': z,
        opacity: '0.8'
    });
    // border, padding have to be applied first, than setting position:
    elem.css({ 
        top: y - elem.height() - offset, // $(this). also possible, but no $.-call needed, because jQ-Object in 'elem' already exists
        left: x - elem.width() - offset,
    });
};
```

Comment: I can go `$(this).width()`? Cool!

Comment: This does not work in the jsFiddle. What does `$(this)` point to in the context of a `.css({})` block?

Comment: I *think* the issue is the div *has not yet been rendered* when the code in the `.css({})` segment is evaluated. As such, `$(this).width()` does not exist.